# How to create TFS/Azure DevOps Work Items query across TFS collections and Export the same to Wor/Excel/Outlook etc. using and API

Tags: api, rest, azure-devops, tfs

We have a script which programmatically creates the Work Items, now we need to export all those work items to Excel/Word/Outlook/etc.

Key point is to have a query across TFS/ADO collections and finally export them to may be excel via an API  if there is any sample to export the Work Items via API it will be great we just have to change the connection strings.

Thanks & Regards
Ankit Khare

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no direct support to export Work Item to excel via APIs. Based on this [Work Items documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0#get-list-of-work-items) which we have form Microsoft, we can see that REST APIs can provide JSON response for work items.

REST API response need to be parsed and excel conversion logic needs to be implemented to get your desired result.

But there is way to export Work Items data to csv **without API**, that is by using `Export to CSV` option in Queries. Check [export list to csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/import-work-items-from-csv?view=azure-devops#export-list-as-csv) for more information. You can specify the data types you need in the csv file via `Column Option`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the reason we are not going in for the export to csv file is because we need to refer multiple collections and different environments.

Comment: I am using the PowerShell script to export data to excel however the concern is to make the collection name and project name dynamic , we should be able to provide inputs for collection and Project. is there a way we can modify the script on this link for exporting work items to Excel? I need the TFS url, collection and Project name to be provided somehow please help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664093/tfs-2017-update-3-1-release-approver-report-history/52737399#52737399